# Adding Google phone conversion tracking to Genesis Framework

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-ads-api, genesis

I am in the process of setting up phone conversion tracking for Google adwords on a Genesis WordPress theme.

I am following instructions on this page: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095883?hl=en#gfn and I am up to part III. The problem I am having is it says to add an onload function to the  tag but because of the Genesis Framework I am struggling to edit the usually straightforward  tag. It should appear as

```
<body onload="_googWcmGet('number', '1-800-123-4567')">.
```

So instead I am trying to achieve the same function by using a jQuery file to do the function, I have created the following and tested it to make sure it is loading on the website but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
_googWcmGet('landline', '0161 123 4567');  
});
```

However the code doesn't seem to be working, what makes it worse is the only way to check if it is working is to use a paid click.. so I want to make sure it is right before testing again.

Is there something wrong with my jQuery that would mean it will not work the same as the body onload as suggested?

Comment: Don't know if you saw these.  These guys were placing it in the body - http://ecommppc.com/2014/09/19/setup-adwords-website-call-tracking-on-your-genesis-theme/   And these came up with a pretty dirty hack that worked http://digitalessence.net/how-to-add-onload-to-the-body-using-genesis-add_filter/

Comment: Hi McNab thank you so much for that, the first link seemed the best way to go and I dropped the script into the footer, tested it this morning and it is working. I can't believe they didn't implement a way to test it without paying for the click! Anyway thanks again.

Comment: Nice one, glad it worked out!